# How to create custmzed list from csv in python 3?

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv file like below

```
Id,Date,P_Sales_Qty,Category
1,2016-03-20,1,17
2,2016-03-23,1,17
3,2016-03-25,2,17
4,2016-03-31,2,17
5,2016-04-02,3,17
6,2016-04-04,1,17
7,2016-04-09,1,17
8,2016-04-10,1,17
9,2016-04-28,1,17
10,2016-04-29,2,17
11,2016-04-30,1,17
```

I want to create a list like :

```
[2016-03-20 1   17
2016-03-23  1   17
2016-03-25  2   17
2016-03-31  2   17
2016-04-02  3   17
2016-04-04  1   17
2016-04-09  1   17
2016-04-10  1   17
2016-04-28  1   17
2016-04-29  2   17
2016-04-30  1   17]
```

Please help on this how can I achieve this?

Comment: `Id` is column or `index` ? What return `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: Id is Column not index

Comment: Thanks, so use my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `values` property for your `dataframe`.

```
list = df.values.tolist()
In[1] : list
Out[1]: [['2016-03-20', 1, 17],
         ..................
         ]
```

The second step is to use `reduce` method in order to obtain a simple list.

```
from functools import reduce
list = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, list)
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, thanks for quick reply , I don't want create nested lists.I want create exact output as I mentioned question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems need:

```
a = df[['Date','P_Sales_Qty','Category']].to_csv(sep=' ', header=None, index=False)
print (a)
2016-03-20 1 17
2016-03-23 1 17
2016-03-25 2 17
2016-03-31 2 17
2016-04-02 3 17
2016-04-04 1 17
2016-04-09 1 17
2016-04-10 1 17
2016-04-28 1 17
2016-04-29 2 17
2016-04-30 1 17
```

Also if wrap it to list get:

```
a = [df[['Date','P_Sales_Qty','Category']].to_csv(sep=' ', header=None, index=False)]
print (a)

['2016-03-20 1 17\n2016-03-23 1 17\n2016-03-25 2 17\n2016-03-31 2 17\n2016-04-02 3 17\n2016-04-04 1 17\n2016-04-09 1 17\n2016-04-10 1 17\n2016-04-28 1 17\n2016-04-29 2 17\n2016-04-30 1 17\n']
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply , I don't want create nested lists.I want create exact output as I mentioned question.

Comment: @saikumar - Do you think 2d array? Check edited answer.

Comment: @jezrael, I think he wants an unwraped list, but its output seems to be strange.

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for reply but i am getting list, for each variable in new line but I want like[ '2016-03-20'  1 17 next line next record like expected output in question

Comment: @saikumar - I am a bit confused, I modify answer, but still not sure what need. Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael, sorry for late reply.we are getting output in string type but a list  which contains Date is string and reaming columns are int

Comment: @saikumar - I think what you need is problematic. Maybe little hack help `df.columns = [''] * len(df.columns)` and then `print (df)`.

Comment: @saikumar - And `df.index = [''] * len(df.index)`